# Interpreting the results of R Mclust package

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I'm using the R package mclust to estimate the number of clusters in my data and get this result:

```
Clustering table:
     2      7      8      9 
205693   4465   2418     91 
Warning messages:
1: In map(z) : no assignment to 1,3,4,5,6
2: In map(z) : no assignment to 1,3,4,5,6
```

I have 9 clusters as the best, but it has no assignment to 5 of the clusters.
So does this mean I want to use 9 or 5 clusters?

If the answer can be found somewhere online, a link would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, the method just did not work at all on your data...

You may try other seeds, because when you "lose" clusters (i.e. they become empty) this usually means your seeds were not chosen well enough. And your cluster 9 is also pretty much gone, too.

However, if your data is actually generated by a mixture of Gaussians, it's hard to find such a bad starting point... so most likely, all of your results are bad, because the data does not satisfy your assumptions.

Judging from your cluster sizes, I'd say you have **1 cluster** and a lot of **noise**...

Have you visualized and validated the results?

Don't blindly follow some number. Validate.